# Swift 3 Ambiguous Use of Subscript

Tags: swift3

Since converting my project to Swift 3, I'm getting an "ambiguous use of subscript" error on the following code:

```
if let alert: AnyObject = alert, let remotetitle = alert["title"] as? String{
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Why are you casting `alert` to `AnyObject` instead of a dictionary of the proper type?

Comment: It was code from a tutorial that worked in Swift 2.  Your question gave me the clue I needed to write it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of your variable `alert`.  The problem is that it cannot apply subscript to type AnyObject

## Subscripts in Swift 3

> Classes, structures, and enumerations can define subscripts, which are shortcuts for accessing the member elements of a collection, list, or sequence. You use subscripts to set and retrieve values by index without needing separate methods for setting and retrieval. For example, you access elements in an Array instance as someArray[index] and elements in a Dictionary instance as someDictionary[key].

Answer (score 2):

Do not annotate an unspecific type, cast to a specific type

```
if let alert = alert as? [String:Any], let remotetitle = alert["title"] as? String {
```

PS: `AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` as a dictionary value.